# How to remove the index.php in the url?

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, nginx

I have installed wordpress in a subdirectory (`blog`). In the root directory I have installed Magento. Now the file directory is as following:

```
app
downloader
includes
media
....
blog/wp-admin
```

My server is **nginx**. When I set the URL in the wordpress  *Permalink Settings* to:

```
http://www.example.com/blog/index.php/sample-post/
```

… all the posts are available. Now I want to remove the `index.php` from that URL. How should I do that? When I set the custom structure to …

```
http://www.example.com/blog/sample-post/
```

… the URLs are not resolved by WordPress and I get a 404.

Comment: What does your .htaccess look like? See http://serverfault.com/questions/206491/what-is-the-nginx-equivalent-to-this-mod-rewrite-rule

Comment: I suggest searching this site for `nginx pretty permalinks`, this has been asked and answered before.

Answer (score 3):

The problem likely has to do with the server settings in Nginx for your blog.  It's likely that the location rules for /blog/ are wrong, specifically try_files.  It should look like this:

```
location /blog/ {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

This tells Nginx the order in which it should try to find the requested resource.  It will first start by trying to find the exact object in the URL.  If that doesn't exist, it'll try to find that object as a directory.  If that doesn't exist, it'll pass the request to index.php along with any arguments or query strings, if present.  Since index.php in the main handler for WordPress, this will trigger WordPress to find the page or post you've requested based on your rewrite rules.

The beautiful thing about this configuration is that you can now change your permalink structure to anything WordPress supports without having to change your Nginx rules.  This is also the recommended method over using explicit rewrite rules in Nginx.

Comment: You'll also want to make sure 'index index.php' is added inside the location rules.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't have idea this actually existed. Just tried it and it's WAY more useful, since I just only have to remember to write it once (and it works for every wordpress site I have in the vps).

Comment: Yup. It's a much more elegant solution than writing `if` statements, and more reliable.

Comment: It will be more helpful if you can add where I can find this code in nginx setting. Like which file to check? nginx.conf?

Answer (score 2):

Place this code in your `functions.php` file

```
   add_filter( 'got_rewrite', '__return_true', 999 );
```

### Update:

[got_mod_rewrite()](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-admin/includes/misc.php#L16) function checks whether the current server is apache or not using [apache_mod_loaded()](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-includes/functions.php#L2970) function. Since we are using nginx it returns false. So wordpress adds index.php in the url.

By using [got_rewrite](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-admin/includes/misc.php#L18) filter we are telling wordpress that we got rewrite in our server.

Comment: i put the code in functions.php. all the post still can't available.

Comment: Try resetting your permalink in the permalinks section. First change it to default settings, then switch back

Answer (score 1):

Add this location object to your server configuration in your nginx.conf.

```
location /blog {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Then restart nginx.

#### Symbolic Linking to Wordpress folder

I'm using a symbolic link to the wordpress folder in my implementation and I found there are still complications when trying to access real folders inside of that symbolic link. There are three of these folders and the `try_files $uri/` part seems to fail here (at least for me), so I ended up manually excluding those folders from being manipulated by `try_files`. If you are having similar issues, try the location block below.

```
location ~* \/blog\/(?!.*(wp-admin|wp-content|wp-includes)).* {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php$args;`. Lack of `$uri/`  will cause looping (e.g. `/wp-admin`  address).

Comment: @nmr you are correct. I have updated my answer. Thank you!